# Speaker recognition - Bad Request error on microsoft oxford

Tags: python, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I am using the python wrapper that has been given in the SDK section. I've been trying to enroll a voice file for a created profile using the python API.

I was able to create a profile and list all profiles successfully. But when I try to enroll a voice (.wav) file with a simple hello world phrase with the created profile, I get the error **'ERROR:root:Error enrolling profile.'** which in the trace tells **'Exception: Error enrolling profile: Bad Request'**. I've used by importing the module to my python file as well as in command line as described in the Readme.

I have no clue whether this API will work or not. I don't think there is any other API for my little experiment. There are no proper responses even in the issues section of the SDK.

PS: This is my first question. Pardon my styles and formats.
The following is the stack trace:

```
ERROR:root:Error enrolling profile.
127.0.0.1 - - [17/May/2016 15:55:44] "POST /verify-voice HTTP/1.1" 500 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [17/May/2016 15:55:44] "POST /verify-voice HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Rajagopal/Development/GitRepos/pet-projects/barabara-server/wsgi/barbara/views/users.py", line 57, in voice_register
    enroll_profile(app.config['MICROSOFT_SPEAKER_RECOGNITION_KEY'], user.speaker_profile_id, _created_file_path)
  File "/Rajagopal/Development/GitRepos/pet-projects/barabara-server/wsgi/oxford/speaker_recognition/Identification/EnrollProfile.py", line 48, in enroll_profile
    enrollment_response = helper.enroll_profile(profile_id, file_path)
  File "/Rajagopal/Development/GitRepos/pet-projects/barabara-server/wsgi/oxford/speaker_recognition/Identification/IdentificationServiceHttpClientHelper.py", line 155, in enroll_profile
    raise Exception('Error enrolling profile: ' + res.reason)
Exception: Error enrolling profile: Bad Request
```

Comment: Consider using code formatting when pasting output or code.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you share the code that triggered this error.

Comment: As i've mentioned I used the python (wrapper) SDK provided in the microsoft documentation page. This is the [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/ProjectOxford-ClientSDK/tree/master/SpeakerRecognition/Python). I Used the Identification/EnrollProfile.py in command prompt with the subscriber id(the API key), created profile id, and the local audio file as mentioned in the Readme

Comment: It seems like an API problem, I've tried hitting the actual endpoint with a POST request along with the documentation specified parameters and headers. I get the response { 'status' : 'Bad request', message: 'Not a valid WAVE file - No RIFF header'. I've tried with multipart/form-data and using file input from postman REST client. I've also tried to hit the API endpoint in the actual console provided by Microsoft (which doesn't have any way to pass the wave file as file input) by encoding the audio file into string(which starts with data:audio/wav;base64..).

Comment: I know its in preview stage, but it should have some understandable instructions and parameter details. The API [link](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/5645c3271984551c84ec6797/console) and documentation [link](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speaker-recognition-api/documentation). I've created an issue in git hub [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/ProjectOxford-ClientSDK/issues/66)

Answer (score 1):

The Speaker Identification code requires that enrollment audio "should be at least 20 seconds long and no longer than 5 minutes. The minimum number of total speech needed for enrollment, after removing silence, is 60 seconds" per [documentation](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/5645c3271984551c84ec6797).

Comment: Thanks @cthrash. Was missing that due to unclear error message.

Comment: You can now enrol and identify using only 1 second if you set the shortAudio parameter to true. However, the new recommended limit is 30 seconds.